# Python Telegram Bot - how to force "standard" keyboard after using reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup()

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot, custom-keyboard

I am creating a Telegram bot using [this](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/index.html) Python library. The flow of the bot will go as follows:

1. Display a menu to the user using a custom keyboard. (Using [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.replykeyboardmarkup.html)())
2. After the user selects "Enter a number", the standard keyboard appears for the user to input a number.
3. Once the number has been sent by the user, the bot replies with "Enter a number using the standard keyboard (again)". It then shows the same menu as a custom keyboard.

I have created this basic function below to test this. I have just included the three steps in one function to specifically try and figure out how the custom keyboard works. I understand that this flow won't actually work to allow the user to input a number.

I just want to see:

**custom keyboard -> normal keyboard -> custom keyboard**

```
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    """Start the conversation and ask user for input."""

    markup1 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([
        ["Enter a number"],
    ])

    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Select an option:",
        reply_markup=markup1,
    )

    time.sleep(3)

    # should display the standard keyboard for the user to input a number,
    # but the custom keyboard from before (markup1) stays
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Enter a number using the standard keyboard:"
    )

    time.sleep(3)

    # essentially the same menu as markup1 but changed to make sure this,
    # displays and it's not just markup1 again
    markup2 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([
        ["Enter a number (again)"],
    ])

    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Enter a number using the standard keyboard (again):", reply_markup=markup2
    )

    return MAIN_MENU
```

I'm not sure whether stripping the program down and testing the logic in a single function like this is the best idea because this flow might actually be causing different problems. But when I was testing different keyboard options with everything else it got a bit confusing.

I can't seem to get it to work how I intend. I don't seem to have a good grasp of how to display the custom keyboard when I want to, and then displaying the normal keyboard when I require the user to input a number.

**Things I've tried**

- I have tried sending a message using "update.message.reply_text" with no "reply_markup" argument. My understanding was that with no "reply_markup" specified, the client would just display the standard keyboard.
- When I tried with "one_time_keyboard" this didn't seem to help.
- I also tried with "reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()" but this seemed to cause other issues.

Any information or advice on this would be greatly appreciated as I'm quite confused with how this library is supposed to be implemented. I haven't posted much here so please let me know if I can provide any more useful information.

Answer (score 1):

If you send a `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`, it will be available until you send `ReplyKeyboardRemove`. The user can choose to hide that custom keyboard (which is also what `one_time_keyboard_does`), but that doesn't remove it. Sending `ReplyKeyboardRemove` is the only way to fully remove the custom keyboard.